# Switch all jQuery tabs on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I'm working with tabs in jQuery to show code segments in different languages (C# and Javascript). When user clicks on one of the tabs, I want all the tabs to switch to the respective language. For example if the user clicks on the Javascript tab, all the other code segments will switch to the Javascript tab.

Here is the jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/XBLAY/) to what I'm doing. Here is my code below:

HTML:

```
  < !-- Tab Set 1 -->
  <div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">C#</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Javascript</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"> <pre class="prettyprint">Some C# code</pre>

    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2"> <pre class="prettyprint">Some Javascript Code</pre>

    </div>
  </div>

  < !-- Tab Set 2 -->
  <div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">C#</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Javascript</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"> <pre class="prettyprint">Some C# code</pre>

    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2"> <pre class="prettyprint">Some Javascript Code</pre>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.tabs").tabs();
});
```

I thought by making my tabs have the same link they would switch whenever one is clicked, but that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Can you try be more clear on what the problem is? It sounds to me like if a uses clicks on Javascript tab, then all other tabs display the code in Javascript. That doesn't sound logical.....?

Comment: Well what should happen is that if a user clicks on a Javascript tab then all the code segments should switch to the Javascript tab as well as show the Javascript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need.

```
$("div.tabs").tabs({
  activate: function( event, ui ) {
    var tabIndex = $(this).tabs('option', 'active');
    $("div.tabs").tabs({active:tabIndex});
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XBLAY/3/

When you select one tab in one tab group, all tab groups select that tab.

Edited the URL to go to the working jsfiddle site.

Comment: Seems to work perfectly in jsfiddle but I can seem to get it to work in an index.html. Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you give me link to webpage so I can check source?

Comment: I'm doing it on local host right now, but [here](http://pastebin.com/9bSB1XXQ) is my test.js and [here](http://pastebin.com/54riXmiE) is my index.html. I copied the code straight from jsfiddle and for some reason it's not working. I feel like I'm missing something small. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Use this javascript http://jsfiddle.net/XBLAY/3/
Old one didn't work cause you must put everything in $(function() { all code here });

Comment: Or if you prefer old construction use this... http://pastebin.com/zQinhFGB

Please just mark this answer accepted, thx :)